# Calling classes from other files within a class

Tags: java

I'm stuck on the final part of my program which involves comparing two separate sorting algorithms.

I am unable to call my other two classes within my main and I'm not entirely sure why.

```
import java.util.Random;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.Scanner;


 // Implement two separate sorting classes
 // Compare both classes and see how they stack up
 // based off their results.

 //QuickSort + BubbleSort
public class a8main{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Type in array size.");
System.out.println("5,000 10,000 30,000");

int input = userInput.nextInt();

//Test smaller arrays starting at 5,000
//Test larger arrays. (30,000 or more)

byte[] c = new byte[input];
new Random().nextBytes(c);

//Begin QuickSorting + BubbleSorting
for (int j=1;j<6;j++)
{
    byte[] c1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(c, 0, 5000*j);
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    quickSort(c1,0,5000*j-1);
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = endTime - startTime;

    byte[] c2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(c, 0, 5000*j);
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    bubbleSort(c2);
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = endTime - startTime;

    System.out.println("Amount of time taken for first array "+5000*j+" elements for quickSort: "+totalTime+" miliseconds.");


    System.out.println("Amount of time taken for second array "+5000*j+" elements for bubbleSort: "+totalTime+" miliseconds.");
}
```

}
}

I've got the main code here and I'm going to include my other two classes just to give you a clue on what I'm dealing with here.

```
public class bubbleSort
 {
     static void bubbleSorter(byte[] args)
 {
  int n = args.length;
  byte temp = 0;
  for(int i=0; i < n;i++)
  {
       for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++)
     {
          if(args[j-1] > args[j])
         {
             temp = args[j-1];
             args[j-1] = args[j];
             args[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

}
}

Bubble Sort

```
      public class quickSort
  {
      static void quickSorter(byte[]args,int low,int high)
   {
    if (args == null || args.length == 0)
        return;

    if (low >= high)
        return;

    int center = low + (high - low) / 2;
    byte pivot = args[center];

    int i = low, j = high;
    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (args[i] < pivot)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while (args[j] > pivot)
        {
            j--;
        }


    }

    if (low < j)
        quickSorter(args, low, j);

    if (high > i)
        quickSorter(args, i, high);
}
```

}

And QuickSort

What am I doing wrong?
I just need some clues.

Comment: You need to qualify the method names with the class name. e.g. `bubbleSort.bubbleSorter(c2);`

Comment: Instantiate the other classes.

Comment: @DanW Thank you so much! I'm still a beginner and these small details are so easy to miss for me. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: My head is spinning from the class names, haha. In Java you should do class names like `BubbleSort` and method names like `bubbleSorter`. But yes, you would use `BubbleSort.bubbleSorter()` to call the static method of another class.

Comment: I added an answer. There were a few other issues with your code. I think it should run if you use my answer. I didn't go over any of the sorting logic. For bonus points, add in merge sort. '-)

Comment: @AngelEscobedo, did any of the answers help at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call methods by the class name as you defined them as static methods like this

```
quickSort.quickSorter(parameter1,parameter2,parameter3);
bubbleSort.bubbleSorter(parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues.

First, Java recommendations are to use [PascalCase](http://wiki.c2.com/?CapitalizationRules) for class names; for example, `BubbleSort`.  Method names are camel case like `bubbleSorter`.  It's way easier to read this way.

Second, you were re-declaring `endTime` and `totalTime` in your `Main` `main()` method.  Take out the `long` before them after your `bubbleSorter()` method call.

Third, you should force your static classes to have a private constructor. Some people throw an exception if anyone tries to initialize the private constructor. This can only really be done within the class, so I opt to just write a comment since people could just remove the exception anyway.

Fourth, when calling static methods of a class you need to include the class of the static method.  This will be way easier to read when you do the first point in this answer.

Here's what your classes could look like.

**Bubble Sort Class:**

```
public class BubbleSort
{
    private BubbleSort() {
        //This is a static class - no instantiation needed
    }

    public static void bubbleSorter(byte[] args)
    {
        int n = args.length;
        byte temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++)
            {
                if (args[j - 1] > args[j])
                {
                    temp = args[j - 1];
                    args[j - 1] = args[j];
                    args[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Quick Sort Class:**

```
public class QuickSort
{
    private QuickSort() {
        //This is a static class - no instantiation needed
    }

    public static void quickSorter(byte[]args,int low,int high)
    {
        if (args == null || args.length == 0)
            return;

        if (low >= high)
            return;

        int center = low + (high - low) / 2;
        byte pivot = args[center];

        int i = low, j = high;
        while (i <= j)
        {
            while (args[i] < pivot)
            {
                i++;
            }
            while (args[j] > pivot)
            {
                j--;
            }


        }

        if (low < j)
            quickSorter(args, low, j);

        if (high > i)
            quickSorter(args, i, high);
    }
}
```

**Main Class:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type in array size.");
        System.out.println("5,000 10,000 30,000");

        int input = userInput.nextInt();

//Test smaller arrays starting at 5,000
//Test larger arrays. (30,000 or more)

        byte[] c = new byte[input];
        new Random().nextBytes(c);

//Begin QuickSorting + BubbleSorting
        for (int j=1;j<6;j++)
        {
            byte[] c1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(c, 0, 5000*j);
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            QuickSort.quickSorter(c1,0,5000*j-1);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long totalTime = endTime - startTime;

            byte[] c2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(c, 0, 5000*j);
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            BubbleSort.bubbleSorter(c2);
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            totalTime = endTime - startTime;

            System.out.println("Amount of time taken for first array "+5000*j+" elements for quickSort: "+totalTime+" miliseconds.");


            System.out.println("Amount of time taken for second array "+5000*j+" elements for bubbleSort: "+totalTime+" miliseconds.");
        }
    }
}
```